# Force HTTP for non WWW and WWW

Tags: .htaccess, http, mod-rewrite, https

I'm trying to force users to HTTP, we don't want people to access our site with HTTPS. The code below redirects to http just fine with someone visits the site with https://www but not with https://website

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

How would I make it do the same thing when people enter the url without the www? The site is being forced with WWW though wordpress.

Thanks!

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} ^on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?(.+)
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]


## EXPIRES CACHING ##
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/png "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType text/css "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/html "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/pdf "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access 1 year"
ExpiresDefault "access 1 month"
</IfModule>
## EXPIRES CACHING ##


# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress

# GZip Ninja Speed -- Starts here
# Do not write anything between "GZip Ninja Speed -- Starts" and "GZip Ninja Speed -- Ends"
# It will be deleted while uninstalling GZip Ninja Speed plugin
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain #GZip Ninja Speed
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html #GZip Ninja Speed
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml #GZip Ninja Speed
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css #GZip Ninja Speed
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml #GZip Ninja Speed
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml #GZip Ninja Speed
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml #GZip Ninja Speed
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript #GZip Ninja Speed
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript #GZip Ninja Speed
AddType x-font/otf .otf #GZip Ninja Speed
AddType x-font/ttf .ttf #GZip Ninja Speed
AddType x-font/eot .eot #GZip Ninja Speed
AddType x-font/woff .woff #GZip Ninja Speed
AddType image/x-icon .ico #GZip Ninja Speed
AddType image/png .png #GZip Ninja Speed
# GZip Ninja Speed -- Ends here
```

Comment: @anubhava I have it set to http://www.example.com why would I use https in there if I'm trying to not allow it?

Comment: @anubhava All good. The only other items besides wordpress/gzip in the htaccess are 301 redirects.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this in your .htacess

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} ^on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?(.+)
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thanks @PanamaJack but after changing it to hat I get this error:  This webpage has a redirect loop

Comment: I think your WP might be causing this. Can you turn off force www in wordpress?  I noticed you mentioned that. Then just use .htaccess.

Comment: Hmm yeah I set the url to http://example.com in the back end of wordpress and still get the redirect loop error.

Comment: I made a small change on the rules. Please try the updated rules.

Comment: Really appreciate you helping out. I changed the code and now it's not redirecting https to http for www or non www. I updated my original post with my entire htaccess file.

Comment: Ok, so what is it that you want it to do now? Is that not what you wanted it to do?

Comment: Sorry if I was unclear. If someone types in https://example.com I want it to redirect them to http://example.com and if someone types in https://www.example.com I want it to redirect them to http://www.example.com essentially just making it impossible for someone to hit a page with https in the url.

Comment: Yes, that what that rule above does. it removes https from either www or non www.

Comment: Actually your originally rule should work that way as well.